# Why does Captain Man yell at Jasper for doing something he asked?

Tags: henry-danger

In the Henry Danger episode, *Hour of Power*, Captain Man's old Sidekick, Drex, traps Rays hands in a Nut Cluster Trap (he also puts his head in a unclockable box that can only unlock with a special key). When Schwoz couldn't get the box off his head, Ray asks if he can get the nut cluster trap off his hands.

When he asks this, Jasper Dunlop says, "I'll get your hands free." And he opens a drawer and pulls out a blaster, aims it at the trap and fires. It hits the trap and comes off. Ray is knocked down. Being indestructible, Captain Man isn't hurt by it. He yells at Jasper for shooting him with the blaster. Why in the *world* would he yell at him? If i were Captain Man, I would thank him for getting my hands free, not yell at him!

Why is Jasper being yelled at for doing what he was told?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Captain Man is indestructible, but he does feel pain like other people.  Actually less than other people, since it just lasts for an instant. So perhaps having the trap shot off his hands was painful enough to make Ray angry.  Ray is not noted for being very reasonable.

Comment: I know but, if he can't feel it, even though he did for a second, why yell at him?